# Google Account: "Invalid JWT Signature." intermittent

Tags: google-oauth, google-account

I am getting an intermittently rare response from:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

- 'http_status_code': 400
- 'error_description': 'Invalid JWT Signature.'
- 'error': 'invalid_grant'

However, using the same credentials just an hour before and afterwards, there is no issue with authentication.

What would cause intermittent failure of authentication?

Comment: Are you switching from different evironments? You can be accessing using different auth files.